# How to store configuration setting in MS dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am new in MS dynamics CRM and want to store the user credentials like userid very similar to what you would store in web.config file or session in ASP.NET,so that while creating new lead or contact i can use the store credentials so that i can add same lead or contact to my external application using store credentials.So please let me know how can i store the user credentials? or provide an link with example that explain the same.Also explain all the steps in details for storing the configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

A neat way to do it is to create custom entity in CRM. You would be able to hold all configuration data in it, including credentials. You can restrict access to the entity for only specified users. Draw back to this solution is that you need to have DataContext created and query information from db. 
Other way is to use a .NET partial class that will hold sensitive data in file that is not versioned, that way whole dev team can use different credentials for each of dev environments.
Third way is to pass credentials during plugin registration, but I have not used this way, and it has too many drawbacks in my opinion (you need to provide credentials for each registered step). 
Good luck!